# How can I make 3d pipes in Maya 2012?

Tags: 3d, maya

I have found several tutorials for older versions of Maya, but, since I am rather inexperienced at using the program, I am finding it difficult to get the results I am seeking.

I want to do what is seen in this video beginning at about the 45 second mark:

-Snap to grid on

-Draw an arc

-Draw a circle with a radius of 0.65 with the proper position relative to the arc

-Surfaces > Extrude (this is where I am having trouble)
etc. . .

I can do the first three steps, but when it comes to extruding the object, I get a completely different shape (a funnel-like shape).  There are comments on the video that suggest using "edit mesh > keep faces together" - this part seems different in Maya 2012 (I find it in Polygons tab, Edit Mesh > Keep faces together) when compared to the version the tutor is using.

I have found the option to keep faces together, but it seems to have no effect on what I am doing.

Can someone help me make 3d pipes in Maya 2012?  I do not necessarily have to do it the way the video tutorial is illustrating - I just need a decent way to make pipes with angles and joints (picture pvc piping under your  sink).

Thank you.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

First you need to select your circle and then shift click and select your arc.
Then go to surface>extrude:

https://i.stack.imgur.com/ZxCVo.png

Comment: Wow, I was drag-selecting them, they appeared selected (to a newb at Maya), apparently they were not.  I tried it thinking it wouldn't behave any differently.  I was wrong.

Thank you very much!

Answer (score 1):

> Wow, I was drag-selecting them, they appeared selected (to a newb at Maya), apparently they were not. I tried it thinking it wouldn't behave any differently. I was wrong. Thank you very much! – user1026898 Jan 23 at 12:09

you did have both items selected with yer "drag select".

But the requirement was not the selection types alone but the "order" of selection as well.

With the drag select...
Maya did not recieve the expected order in regards to type criteria. ( thus the first answer suggesting that u "shift select" that correct order" )

In the feedback bar on the bottom gui and in the echo portion of the script editor...
Maya will give you feedback step by step asking you to fullfill each selection requirement. 
Try it again and pay close attention to the command line feedback during each action and you will find that Maya will provide the criteria for every action.